# Excel macro to import CSV files overwrite existing workbook tabs

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

The following code originated from the very helpful info at rondebruin.nl. It imports selected csv files into separate tabs in a xls workbook. There are two things I would like to change.

I cannot find the answer to this on this site or in a general search and I would much appreciate some help from the experts here, hope this is of interest to others...

1) the code currently overwrites or deletes the existing first sheet in the workbook from which it is run -- I would like to keep a single sheet at the front of this workbook under all circumstances

2) on subsequent runs, new tabs are added after exiting tabs -- I would like to overwrite existing tabs when re-importing the same csv file.

...appreciate any help...

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
        "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
        "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
#End If

Function ChDirNet(szPath As String) As Boolean
'based on Rob Bovey's code
    Dim lReturn As Long
    lReturn = SetCurrentDirectoryA(szPath)
    ChDirNet = CBool(lReturn <> 0)
End Function

Sub Get_CSV_Files()
'For Excel 2000 and higher
    Dim Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim basebook As Workbook
    Dim CSVFileNames As Variant
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim ExistFolder As Boolean

    'Save the current dir
    SaveDriveDir = CurDir

    'You can change the start folder if you want for
    'GetOpenFilename,you can use a network or local folder.
    'For example ChDirNet("C:\Users\Ron\test")
    'It now use Excel's Default File Path

    ExistFolder = ChDirNet("C:\test")
    If ExistFolder = False Then
        MsgBox "Error changing folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    CSVFileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (filefilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(CSVFileNames) Then

        On Error GoTo CleanUp

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        'Add workbook with one sheet
        'Set basebook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        Set basebook = ThisWorkbook

        'Loop through the array with csv files
        For Fnum = LBound(CSVFileNames) To UBound(CSVFileNames)

            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(CSVFileNames(Fnum))

            'Copy the sheet of the csv file after the last sheet in
            'basebook (this is the new workbook)
            mybook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:= _
                                     basebook.Sheets(basebook.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = Right(CSVFileNames(Fnum), Len(CSVFileNames(Fnum)) - _
                                            InStrRev(CSVFileNames(Fnum), "\", , 1))
            On Error GoTo 0

            mybook.Close savechanges:=False

        Next Fnum

        'Delete the first sheet of basebook
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        basebook.Worksheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

CleanUp:

        ChDirNet SaveDriveDir

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Comment out basebook.Worksheets(1).Delete to stop deleting the sheet.  Give the second of your questions a try and post back with what you are having problems with.

Answer (score 3):

You are deleting your first worksheet with this line of code:

```
    basebook.Worksheets(1).Delete
```

as it says in the comments.  If you don't want to do that, then you shouldn't have that line in there. I presume the worksheet that keeps disapearing is that one.

As far as your desire to overwrite tabs with new data instead of creating new tabs, you might create a search for the tab name first and if that tab exists, then copy and paste the CSV onto that sheet.  If it doesn't exist create a new tab with that name and paste the data into a new tab.

Comment: Thankyou to all for the help, and such swift response. It seems so obvious when pointed out by someone who knows, but I couldn't see the wood for the trees.